# correctly interpret histogram for normal distribution

Tags: statistics, histogram, gaussian, normal-distribution

Below is the histogram plot of some timeseries data. I was trying to find anomalies in the data. First basic method which i thought to try was : if the data follows the normal distribution then anything above or below 3 standard deviations will be considered as an outlier. Histogram doesn't really look like a bell curve or may be i am interpreting it wrong? I also did some normality checks like Shapiro-Wilk Test, D’Agostino and Pearson’s Test & Anderson-Darling Test , according to all of them my data is not normal. Still i wanted to apply 3 standard-deviations concept (Z score) and check if i am able to identify anomalies or not. So, i did and below is the result. Seems, like anomalies are correctly identified. Am i not understanding the histogram correctly then?
[image][image]

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if the histogram looks like a Gaussian distribution, then it makes sense to apply 3 standard-deviations concept. However, it's not a required condition. 3 standard-deviations concept only rely on mean and standard deviation. In my opinion, it's more a question of judgement.

In your case, applying this method gives coherent results because your measures are kind of grouped around the mean (for the main mode).

Comment: does my histogram looks like gaussian?

Comment: No it doesn't, but that's not required.

Considering your measures, you should plot a finer histogram (0.02 step on abscisse) if you really want to assess the kind of distribution. But I don't think it will give you valuable information.